# close parent colorbox inside the colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a Colorbox inside a Colobox with some buttons, I want to close the parent colorbox from child colorbox on button click, how to accomplish it?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Plaese add some code about what have you tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using

```
parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
```

Comment: Good answer. This use case is clearly documented on the plugin's site.